# VBScript Rename folder error "Premission Denied"

Tags: vbscript

I have been trying to find the answer but no exact match for my question.

below is a snippet of the script just to rename the folder, this doesn't give me a err and continue it just stops.

at the beginning of the script and general most of my script have "Option Explicit"
so I thought maybe that stopped it and I used "On Error Resume Next" but it still stops.

I know how I get the error its because I have a file open in the directory I'm trying to 'rename' what I'm attempting to do its get the script to say 'sorry you have a file open in that directory' and continue to the next folder...

Can you please help me solve this,

```
objFSO.MoveFolder (folder1),(folder2)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
  WScript.Echo Err.Number
End If
```

Cheers,

Pav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put `On Error Resume Next` just below the `Sub`? You should also Clear the Error.

I believe you are running the vbs in command prompt using cscript:

```
Sub RenameFolders()
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Add your codes

    objFSO.MoveFolder (folder1),(folder2)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "sorry you have a file open in that directory"
        WScript.Echo Err.Description
        WScript.Echo Err.Number
        Err.Clear ' Clear the ERROR!
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had at the beginning the line 'On Error Resume Next'
but not in the sub its self....... put it in the sub and it worked a dream!

Comment: It's pointless to clear the error when you're just about to leave the scope where error handling is enabled. That would only make sense if `OERN` were set globally. However, global `OERN` should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, so i removed the OERN at the beginning of my script and only have it in my subroutine now.

I also tried the remove the Err.Clear but what it tells me is that it couldnt rename the next folder as well, but it actually did.

In my code I basically have a array with 6 folders and I run a loop to go through and rename the folders and display at the end

-done
-ERR
-done
-didnt exist
-done
-ERR

Comment: I put in `Err.Clear` because I know you have it in a loop. I think it's a good practice to clear the error if you intend to check on error status.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SPath 'As String
Dim DPath 'As String

SPath = "d:\test1"
DPath = "E:\test1"

Call MoveFolders(SPath ,DPath)


Sub MoveFolders(PSPath,PDPath)
  '-----------------------------
  PSPath = Trim(PSPath)
  PDPath = Trim(PDPath)
  '-----------------------------
  Dim objFso  'AS Object
  Dim objFil  'As Object
  Dim objMFld 'As Object
  Dim objSFld 'As Object
  '/*----------------------------
  Dim DestFullPath     'As String 
  Dim DestFullFilePath 'As String 
  '----------------------------------------------------
  Set objFso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  '----------------------------------------------------
  If objFso.FolderExists(PSPath) Then
    Set objMFld = objFso.GetFolder(PSPath)
    '----------------------------------------------------
    If Not objFso.FolderExists(PDPath) Then
       objFso.CreateFolder(PDPath)
    End If
    '----------------------------------------------------  
    For Each objSFld In objMFld.SubFolders
      DestFullPath = Replace(objSFld, PSPath, PDPath ,1, 1, vbTextCompare)
      '/*------------------------
      Call MoveFolders(objSFld,DestFullPath)
      '/*------------------------
    Next
    '/*------------------------
    For Each objFil In  objFso.GetFolder(PSPath).Files
      '/*------------------------
        DestFullFilePath = PDPath & "\" & objFil.Name
      '/*------------------------
      If objFso.FileExists(DestFullFilePath) Then
         objFSO.DeleteFile(DestFullFilePath)
      End If
      '/*------------------------
      objFso.MoveFile objFil , PDPath & "\"
    Next
    '/*------------------------
    If objFso.GetFolder(PSPath).Files.Count = 0 And objFso.GetFolder(PSPath).SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
       objFso.DeleteFolder PSPath
    End If
    '------------------------------
  End If
End Sub
```